# Can you make a Bootstrap Carousel change the ads with refresh instead of rotating by time?

Tags: bootstrap-carousel

I have a client who wants to a/b test her ad but the only option I have for this on my site is bootstrap carousel and I don't know how to stop the carousel and make the image change at refresh. Is this possible or am I dreaming!  Thank you for any help!